# Rubymine doesn't find gem installed already by Terminal

Tags: rubygems, rubymine

I install first gem by Terminal (Ubuntu) typing : sudo gem install  
and then my Rubymine doesn't find any new . So I need again install  by Rubymine -> settings , etc. Why Rubymine doesn't find packets installed by Terminal ?

If You've heard something before about it , please link. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda annoying, rubymine by default creates it's own gemset, you need to open the run configuration and make rubymine use the same ruby/gems that you are using on terminal

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Disable the checkbox `Run the script in context of the bundle (bundle exec)` at `Run` -> `Edit Configurations`, `Bundler` tab (to run with the same gems as in terminal)
2. Add the gem in project bundle

Option #2 is possible if your project is for example using [bundler](http://bundler.io) to manage gem versions.

- For example in a [rails](http://rubyonrails.org) project, look for `Gemfile` at the project root and add the required gem there.